# Can't put an image as android activity background

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, background

I'm trying to put an image as background, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

This is my activity_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/startbackg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="153dp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Hello" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the StartActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    }

}
```

In eclipse I can see correctly the background, like this:

[image: eclipse preview]

But when I run it in a nexus 7, I can't see any background image

[image: app in phone]

I don't know what to try... any ideas?

This is the image I'm using

[image]

Comment: Can you check for logcat if there is any warning like bitmap size is too high some thing like that?

Comment: I didn't see anything in logcat. The image is 1080x1920, the same resolution as the nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        myLInearLayout.setBackground(myImage);
        myLInearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(myImage);

    } else {

        myLInearLayout.setBackground(myImage);

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this?

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is used for the api version lower than the jellybean , this method become deprecated after jellybean so i used set background in else statement

Comment: But the OP has set background in XML